# Newbie in Programming - more effecient sumOfDigits

Tags: java, performance

I came out with this Java code to solve sumOfDigits.

```
 public static int sumOfDigits(int num){
        if (num == 0){
             return 0;
        }
        return num%10+ sumOfDigits(num/10);
    }
```

Well I know this works, but I'm hoping anyone would share insights or materials(some formal terms/knowledge) on how to improve code efficiency, as I know Java does not support recursion that well.

Comment: What gives you the impression Java does not support recursion well?

Comment: 0_o Java supports recursion just fine...

Comment: Oops I might have used a wrong term. "does not support" - I mean recursion run slower than normal while/for loop.

Comment: @rtyusolf: No, "recursion" is the right term for the above. Java (both the language and the VM) is really quite good at it. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Whether Java does or does not support recursion, a typical first stage of any optimsation is to remove any recursive functions.  They're hardly ever the most optimal way of writing anything.

Comment: In a lot of cases, recursion is the more natural way to express and implement an algorithm. And the first stage of any optimisation is certainly not to remove any recursive function, it is to profile your application to understand where your code is inneficient. If it's in a recursive function, change that. If it's not, don't touch your recursive functions.

Comment: Thank you James.. I should have said recursive function not recursion.. anyway I shall remove the recursive function

Comment: @James Gunna go ahead and say a typical first stage is to remove recursive functions is false. First stage is certainly more often profiling, as reimplementing recursive routines is not always most time efficient in terms of dev

Comment: The fact that you used recursion is impressive -- it's actually one of the concepts that a lot of people struggle with. If, to you, recursion is something that seems natural, I suspect that you'll have a bright future in programming. Also, as a newcomer it's important to learn important phrases that mark you as "one of us." Practice saying "Premature optimization is the root of all evil," before any discussion of code performance!

Comment: @LarryOBrien Thanks. Not necessary to say that it seems natural to me, But I have a habit of coding without first trying to introduce too many new variables/loops/arrays and reuse the function more or it will become harder to debug for a beginner like me.. I know now that it's common to have non-optimized code at first, and work your way to improve its efficiency... But I still struggle with what defines efficiency/optimized... All i know is I have a block of codes which work..

Comment: @rtyusolf Avoiding "too many new variables/loops/arrays and reuse the function more" is exactly the right instinct. Lots of people try to put more and more into a function but the best function is one that does exactly one thing correctly and precisely. The key to elegance is not adding code, it's removing code.

Comment: Thank you all I will try to look up Profiling in wiki

Comment: In my line of work (games) the most often reason for using recursion within a game engine is for tree traversal for searching, either for objects, or ray casting into a 3D scene, etc. and that's usually one of the first things that appears in a profile.  :)

Comment: Since this is a working code, a better site to make this questions is http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @madth3 thanks I shall do that next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recursion is not a bad tool at all in Java. Sure, theoretically every function call has a cost, but the JIT compiler is often able to optimize that by itself at runtime and offer a good performance. You should not optimize a function that is clearly written with recursion with another which is more cumbersome without it, except if you really experience problems, but I doubt you'll have any with that code. With experience you'll see that code legibility matters a lot.

To answer your question, the other way to implement what you want is simply to loop until num equals 0 and storing the result of division per 10 in num every time:

```
int total = 0;
while (num != 0) {
    total += num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. It's not really a problem to write in other ways. 
But I just want to focus on why and when I need to write in other ways. Also how to know which one runs faster/or takes up less space, as I'm not quite sure what space meant.